# Alternatives to open source work (on a CV)

Tags: resume, developer

These days in the IT Sphere it seems nearly mandatory to have some open source work in accessible GitHub account listed on your CV.

As someone cursed with a laser-like focus when it comes to developing, I don't have the breadth of mind, energy or drive to code something ELSE in my spare time, away from work.

What are alternatives to open source work to compensate for this modern 'gap' in my CV, and how can I present my CV in such a way the gap will be glossed over?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What projects can I write in my resume if all my company projects are confidential?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-projects-can-i-write-in-my-resume-if-all-my-company-projects-are-confidenti)

Comment: see also: [When looking for a new job how can I market my skills if subject to a strict confidentiality clause?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/33662/when-looking-for-a-new-job-how-can-i-market-my-skills-if-subject-to-a-strict-con)

Comment: @gnat I am not sure this problem is limited to confidentiality. I frankly do not know why this is such a hot item on CVs, hence why I don't know what could replace it.

Comment: The suggested duplicates make no sense to me but your question probably is unanswerable here. If we accept your questionable premise you're basically asking "*I should have X on my resume but don't want to do X. How can I make up for not having X on there?*". To which the obvious answer is "anything equivalent to X", which is a shopping question. And while people certainly obsess over open source contributions when giving job searching advice, I've never found it to be a must-have. The value or otherwise of such experience might make a better question, if we don't have one like it already.

Comment: @Lilienthal I think you are right that such would make a better question. I am rather terrible at phrasing questions in this format though, I will admit.

Comment: @WeckarE. Well you've had a few closed questions recently but I think it's a matter of scope, not phrasing. Your questions are very clear and concise, you're just asking stuff that isn't really suited to a Q&A format. I'd suggest checking the [help/on-topic] again and perhaps asking for help in reformulating this question or asking a new one on [chat].

Comment: @Lilienthal I will do that. I mostly find it difficult to predict how I can scope a question so it produces relevant answers without making it TOO specific. I suppose my focus on hypotheticals is a main issue in using Workplace, in particular.

Comment: having open source stuff is not a 'must have' so your basic premise is flawed. It's completely up to the interviewers etc,. whether they see open source work as beneficial or detrimental, or discount it entirely. It doesn't mean much to me if I was interviewing. A possible handicap even if there is a lot.

Comment: an alternative if it must be free is to have what I call volunteer projects. These are a bit like open source in that anyone can use them, but the source code is not available.

Comment: Why do you think it is mandatory? Maybe you are looking at wrong/unsuitable job listings.