# How can I market myself when all of my work is confidential to my employer?

Tags: resume, job-search

I work as a software engineer for a government agency in a field that is classified, and so I cannot share it with other prospective employers. When my contract expires next year, I plan to pursue work in the private sector.

Unfortunately, because of the nature of my work, I will be unable to showcase or even describe any of my work beyond very high-level descriptors ("I worked with this technology to accomplish this very vague goal.") This is my first coding job after switching career paths, and I realize that it would be objectively difficult for someone who's never met me to tell the difference between my legitimate work experience and someone who is telling tough-to-disprove lies in order to look better on paper. While I'm confident that I could make my way through the interview process to display competence, I worry about making it to that stage. Any HR rep worth their salt will select the candidate who can give a clear description of an impressive accomplishment over the candidate who cannot.

To that end, I'm planning to try to implement some independent projects on my personal gitHub that can showcase some skills and some technologies that I haven't necessarily used at work. I'm hoping that these can help to fill in the gap, but since I'm doing this in addition to my full time job, I won't have nearly as much to showcase as I would if I were allowed to show off my full time work.

I have 9 months until my contract is up. What can and should I do to look as attractive as possible to prospective new employers by the time those 9 months have expired?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What projects can I write in my resume if all my company projects are confidential?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-projects-can-i-write-in-my-resume-if-all-my-company-projects-are-confidenti)

Comment: Yes! That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!